# Is it possible to work with more than one array in vuetify v-autocomplete?

Tags: vuetify.js

Normally one would just make a simple join to merge both arrays in one array, the problem is that i have arrays with different object structures, and depending on the type of object, i need to pass a different value.

Example:

```
array 1: fruits.type.name
array 2: animals.family.name
```

Is there any possibility other than having to craft a custom component from scratch using something like v-text-input, for example?

Answer (score 2):

You mean something like this? Check this codesanbox I made:
https://codesandbox.io/s/stack-71429578-switch-autocomplete-array-757lve?file=/src/components/Example.vue

[image: Example]

```js
 computed: {
      autoArray() {
         return this.typeAnimal ? this.animals : this.fruits
      },
      autoTypeId() {
         return this.typeAnimal ? 'family.id' : 'type.id'
      },
      autoText() {
         return this.typeAnimal ? 'family.name' : 'type.name'
      }
   }
```

With help of a couple computed props you could be able to switch array, item-text and item-value depending of the array you're working with.

Comment: That's a cool idea!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there's no easy way to supply two different arrays to `v-autocomplete` and retain the search functionality.

You could probably join the arrays and write a [custom filter property](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-autocomplete/#props-filter). Then use `selection` and `item` slots to change the output of the `select` based on the structure.

But if your data arrays aren't too complicated, I would avoid the above. Instead, I would loop through both arrays, and build a new combined one with a coherent structure.